# Display NSDecimalNumber in Cell's UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to display an `NSDecimalNumber` in a `UILabel` on my TableView Cell (I'm grabbing a price from BuyProductVariant). I can't seem to get the code right. The warning I get is:

> "Incompatible Pointer Types Assigning to NSString from
>   NSDecimalNumber".

I assume that just means I can't assign an `NSDecimalNumber` because it should be a string. So I change it to an `NSString` instead, and I still get a warning. What should the below code look like instead?

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDecimalNumber *price;
```

**.m**

```
BUYProductVariant *productPrice = price[indexPath.row];
cell.priceLabel.text = productPrice.price;
```

Comment: You say you changed it to an `NSString`. Where's your code that creates an `NSString` from the `NSDecimalNumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to ask for its `description`:

```
cell.priceLabel.text = productPrice.price.description;
```

(All those answers that suggest formatting with `"%@"` are using `description`, indirectly.)

But if it's a price, you probably want to format it like a price. For example, in the USA, prices in US dollars are normally formatted with two digits to the right of the decimal point and a comma before every group of three digits to the left of the decimal point. So instead of using `description`, you should add an `NSNumberFormatter` to your controller and use that:

### .m

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    self.priceFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    // If you don't want a currency symbol like $ in the output, do this:
    // self.priceFormatter.currencySymbol = nil;
}

- (void)showPrice:(NSDecimalNumber *)price inTextField:(UILabel *)label {
    label.text = [self.priceFormatter stringFromNumber:price];
}
```

There are lots of other `NSNumberFormatter` properties you can use to tweak the output, so check the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/) if you need to.

#### UPDATE

Assuming `price` is declared as `NSArray`:

```
BUYProductVariant *productPrice = price[indexPath.row];
cell.priceLabel.test = [self.formatter stringWithNumber:productPrice.price];
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `description`. It's output isn't documented and it could change over time (look at how `NSDate description` changed a few years ago).

Comment: Please note that the output format of `-[NSDecimalNumber descriptionWithLocale:]` (which is what `stringValue` calls) is also undocumented.

Comment: At least `descriptionWithLocale:` formats the number based on the user's locale.

Comment: It would if you passed the locale, but `stringValue` is documented to pass `nil` for the locale, and that means `stringValue` won't localize either: “Use `nil` if you don’t want the description formatted.”

Comment: Oops. My mistake. I was thinking the `nil` locale meant that it would used the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

A UILabel expects its text value to be an NSString, so you need to create a string using the value of product.price.

```
cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", product.price];
```

What's important is that you can't simply cast (change) the type of NSDecimalNumber, you have to convert the value in some way.

Comment: This isn't ideal because the format won't be appropriate for the user's locale.